# Compare Column A in 2 sheets and List only the differences in a 3rd sheet

Tags: excel, match

I have a spreadsheet with 3 tabs.

Tab 1 is master data, Tab 2 is data returned from a report. I need to compare the Data in tab 1 under column A and see if it is in Tab 2 Column A and if it is not list that data in Column A in Tab 3.

Hope that makes sense.
C

Comment: Please tell what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have used this, but has to compare all lines then filter out the ones i dont need.  =IF(VLOOKUP(Table1[@[Emp. No.]],'System Data'!A:A,1,FALSE), "Found", "Not Found") im just looking for a list of missing data in sheet 2

Comment: What's wrong with using that method you just described?

Comment: I only want a list of missing data because it feeds into something else. With this method i need to intervene and sort delete the "found" and resort. Im hoping that it will just do it for me

Comment: The formula you want to get will require more time to finish evaluating and possible take more time than your current method (i.e. 1 vlookup then remove 'Found'). Are you ok with that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clearly explained but I think I've understood.

I think you're trying to define a column in Tab3-Column_A for each row with following information: a text which shows that information from Tab2 exists in Tab1, and if doesn't, put in Tab3 corresponding data from Tab1.

Well, in that case, I'll define a cell in Tab3 which check existence of data from Tab2 in Tab1:

```
=match('Tab2'!A2,'Tab1'!A$2:A$1001, 0)
```

> Note that I've supposed that data start on row #2 if you have a header. Otherwise, edit to start from #1.

This command returns #N/A if doesn't match and number of Tab1 row where it is if matches.

---

Next step is take Tab1 data if didn't match, I say, if Tab3 data is #N/A (return of match function).
Joining two commands in the same cell:

```
=if(isna(match('Tab2'!A2,'Tab1'!A$2:A$1001, 0)),'Tab1'!A2, "Tab2 value exists in Tab1 for this row")
```

I hope to have helped you.